# The best way to save a giant amount of characters

Tags: string, memory-management, vb6

I need to save `a lot` of characters, then, after I save all the information I'll use a `Print`

I tried to use a class as `csStringBuilder` but the error still happening. This is what I tried to do:
Obs: I know it is far away of a good programming, but I tried...

```
Select Case iFlag

     Case 0, 1
         Length= Len(strCurrentlyData)
         If (Len(strCurrentlyData) + Len(strNewData) < (57000000 - Length)) Then
             iFlag = 1
             strCurrentlyData= strCurrentlyData & strNewData
         Else
             iFlag = 2
             strCurrentlyData2= strCurrentlyData2 & strNewData
         End If

     Case 2
         Length = Len(strCurrentlyData2)
         If (Len(strCurrentlyData2) + Len(strNewData)) < (57000000 - Length) Then
             strCurrentlyData2= strCartasDeCobranca2 & strNewData
         Else
             iFlag = 3
             strCurrentlyData3 = strCurrentlyData3 & strNewData
         End If
```

I'm doing this 'till `strCurrentlyData10`, **BUT**
As much as I do this, it will consume more `memory`... So, the `MaxLength` will never be the same, that's why I get this error:

```
                 Out Of String Space
```

Wich would be the best way to work around this ?

Comment: What are you attempting to do with this string?

Comment: Use a `Print` to print a document @jth41

Comment: @jth41 I know it is a bad programming, but this software is old, I don't want to remake it right now, Because I need it for yesterday you know ? That's why I want a work around this. I Need to get `All` the information before I use the `Print`.

Comment: You can use `Put` to append `strNewData` to a temp file. `Print` this temp file instead. You will never be able to handle more than 1.5-2GB of strings in a single VB6 (32-bit) process. Using a file is a cheap way to handle 2GB+ of data.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you keep adding things to an array (keep resizing it as new elements want to be added).  Then you can, at the end, join all the strings into one, if needed (in some sort of chunks).  Or write them out to disk.

If you can elaborate on what your end goal is, there is likely an easier, less hacky solution.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264524(VS.60).aspx):

> Expressions requiring that temporary strings be created for evaluation
> may cause this error. For example, the following code causes an Out of
> string space error on some operating systems:
>
> ```
>     MyString = "Hello"
>     For Count = 1 To 100
>     MyString = MyString & MyString
>     Next Count
> ```

To solve the problem, try [this fast string builder](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Techniques/StringBuilder/article.asp) from VBAccelerator, with an explanation of how it works.

Comment: Thanks Mark ! But I already have that `StringBuilder` and I get the same error =x. I was using a VirtualMachine (VirtualBox) to run vb6.  
And it was with just 1GB RAM. I upgraded to 2GB and I `"solved"` the problem... But the error persists.

Comment: Oh dear! You can also get that error if you try to create a "very large" string in VB6. AFAICR there is an upper limit which seems to be a few hundred megabytes in practise, and increasing the amount of RAM on the machine does not help. Your mileage may vary. You may just have to avoid using a very large string in VB6

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood myself... The error is gone when using the method I showed above. But persists within the `StringBuilderClass` ;P